# How to print the value outside the scope in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app

$scope.compdata value is printing inside the function. but not on the outside the function.

```
 $scope.compdata="";
    $scope.fetchCompanies = function() {
      Company.get({
        arg1 : 'list',
        arg2 : 14
      }, function(success) {
      //  console.log(success);
        $scope.compdata = success.data;
       console.log($scope.compdata);
      });
    };

  $scope.fetchCompanies();   //

    console.log("outside : ",  ?);
```

Comment: The same way you printed inside the function.

Comment: It doesn't make good sense to try to access `$scope.compdata` right after that function call, because it gets assigned in the predicate of an AJAX GET request.  The request may not yet have had time to complete, and hence the value could be undefined when you go to access it.

Comment: Its not working..

Comment: If `Company.get` is an AJAX call, printing `$scope.compdata` outside the `fetchCompanies` function will print a blank string.

Comment: There aren't really any workarounds, except that you should structure your logic such that your code only uses the value if the call completed successfully.

Comment: as you are fetching data from AJAX i.e. async call , you may not be able to print the variable outside. However you may try to wrap `$scope.compdata` inside `$timeout` function. like , `$timeout(function(){
    console.log($scope.compdata);
},100)` But this is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about how Promises work in JavaScript. I assume that `Company.get` is an AJAX call, and since AJAX calls are asynchronous, printing the result just after the call won't work.

Instead you may try this approach:

```
$scope.compdata = "";

$scope.fetchCompanies = function() {
  return Company.get({ // Notice this line
    arg1 : 'list',
    arg2 : 14
  }, function(success) {
    $scope.compdata = success.data;
    console.log($scope.compdata);
    return Promise.resolve(success.data); // and this line
  }).$promise; // and this line
};

$scope.fetchCompanies()
  .then(function(data) { // and this block
    console.log("outside : ",  data);
  });
```

The above code returns the promise itself from the function, so that you can provide a `.then()` and do something with the response. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks . after executing this i am getting an error like then is not a function.

Comment: @Bhavani -- Seems like you're using Angular `$resource` in your code. Try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $q service for this:

```
$scope.compdata = "";

$scope.fetchCompanies = function() {
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 Company.get({
    arg1 : 'list',
    arg2 : 14
  }, function(success) {
    $scope.compdata = success.data;
    console.log($scope.compdata);
    deferred.resolve(success.data); //Edited here
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};

$scope.fetchCompanies()
  .then(function(data) { // and this block
    $scope.compdata = data; //Added
    console.log("outside : ",  $scope.compdata);
  });
```

inject $q in controller as DI

Comment: In the controller i have given $q then also its not working.

Comment: $scope.fetchCompanies()
    .then(function(data) { // and this block
      console.log($scope.compdata);
    });

console.log($scope.compdata);

Comment: In this second console is not working.. I need to use $scope.compdata through out the controller.

Comment: please refer new Edit.